# How to reuse a CSS class, of a webpage, in a created div?

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey

I want to reuse the certain class of CSS style of a webpage to the new Div element that I have added. I am using Greasemonkey to redesign the page.

How can I add `bar1` style to `myDiv`?

**Original div:**

```
<div id="bar1" class="bar1">
```

**New Div:**

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - How to add div class to createElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115310/javascript-how-to-add-div-class-to-createelement)

Answer (score 0):

```
myDiv.className = 'bar1';
```

or

```
myDiv.className = document.getElementById ('bar1').className;
```

Comment: I can see myDiv class name is 'bar1' when I checked with firebug, but still the style is not applied to that myDiv. any idea?

Comment: Some other CSS takes precedence then.  Link to the page in question or post a pared-down page that demos the problem at http://pastebin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your end goal is really to make something like a bookmarklet.  If you are just looking to add a class you can always just set the "className" on a object since the word 'class' is protected.

http://jsfiddle.net/scispear/tCzZM/

I also threw in something style sheet dynamically (but only for more modern browsers, older browsers require a bunch more work).

Comment: This is a Greasemonkey question, so technically the only browser that matters is Firefox -- unless stated otherwise. (In which case it is more properly a "userscripts" question.)

Comment: Bookmarklet was just speculation (you can also get greasemonkey working on chrome).  My jsfiddle only showed how to add classes with and without jquery, it is browser agnostic...

Answer (score 0):

Due to CSS inheritance, copying the class name is not enough, unless the new element is a sibling of the other. Even then, CSS3 selectors like `nth-child` may mess things up.

You should instead iterate over all relevant style properties and copy their computed values like so:

```
var stylesToCopy = ['color', 'background-color', ...];
var oldStyle = getComputedStyle(bar1);
for (var i = 0; i < stylesToCopy.length; i++) {
    myDiv.style[stylesToCopy[i]] = oldStyle[stylesToCopy[i]];
}
```