# how to add style in table which is dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client

how to add border into my table which table is dynamically generated..here is the code..

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');   

    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');

    var text1 = document.createTextNode('Text1');
    var text2 = document.createTextNode('Text2');

    td1.appendChild(text1);
    td2.appendChild(text2);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Now how can i add style on my table.I wanted to give border in it.

Comment: What does this have to do with `asp.net`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a class to DOM element in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115310/how-to-add-a-class-to-dom-element-in-javascript)

Comment: it has audience so somebody can help me..

Comment: That is not how tags work.

Comment: even if it has audience it is not  a good way to find help

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to give a class to the table after creating it using `setAttribute`

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.setAttribute("class", "border_class");
```

and in your CSS add the border styles

```
.border_class {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

So whenever it gets the class(`.border_class`), the styles are automatically applied

```js
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.setAttribute("class", "border_class");
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');   

    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');

    var text1 = document.createTextNode('Text1');
    var text2 = document.createTextNode('Text2');

    td1.appendChild(text1);
    td2.appendChild(text2);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
.border_class {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

before `document.body.appendChild(table);` write:

```
table.style.border = 'solid 1px black';
```

More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `classList` property to `add()` CSS classes.

```
 table.classList.add('myTable')
```

```js
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.classList.add('myTable')
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');

  var td1 = document.createElement('td');
  var td2 = document.createElement('td');

  var text1 = document.createTextNode('Text1');
  var text2 = document.createTextNode('Text2');

  td1.appendChild(text1);
  td2.appendChild(text2);
  tr.appendChild(td1);
  tr.appendChild(td2);

  table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
.myTable {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define border in a `class` and add class to your `table` with `table.className`.

```js
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');   

    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');

    var text1 = document.createTextNode('Text1');
    var text2 = document.createTextNode('Text2');

    td1.appendChild(text1);
    td2.appendChild(text2);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    table.appendChild(tr);
}
table.className="tbl";
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
.tbl{
  border:2px solid #000000;
}
```

On the other hand you can just style all the `table elements` or give `id` to `table element` and write specific styles to it.

```js
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');   

    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');

    var text1 = document.createTextNode('Text1');
    var text2 = document.createTextNode('Text2');

    td1.appendChild(text1);
    td2.appendChild(text2);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    table.appendChild(tr);
}
table.id="tblBordered";
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
table#tblBordered{
  border:2px solid #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table.style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";`

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');

    var text1 = document.createTextNode('Text1');
    var text2 = document.createTextNode('Text2');

    td1.appendChild(text1);
    td2.appendChild(text2);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    table.appendChild(tr);
}
table.style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set table border to 1:

```
table.style.border = "1";
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  table.style.border = "1px solid black";
  
  for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');   

    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    
    tr.style.border = "1px solid black";
    td1.style.border = "1px solid black";
    td2.style.border = "1px solid black";
    
    var text1 = document.createTextNode('Text1');
    var text2 = document.createTextNode('Text2');

    td1.appendChild(text1);
    td2.appendChild(text2);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(table); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

1.) By using `style` attribute which is attached to the DOM object.

```
var table = document.createElement('table');    
table.style.border = '1px solid black';
```

2.) By using `setAttribute()` method.

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.setAttribute("class", "tbl-border");
```

And add the border styles in your CSS file.

```
.tbl-border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

NB: The preferred way to add styles in your element is the second one, using the setAttribute() method.